# Custom Cell over lapping

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to use a custom cell, 
My custom cell is of size 320*220 pixels.
My table size is 320* by 1500 which is large enough
I have set custom cell's view in scale to fill mode. 
But when i fill the table using custom cell all i see is first row. i have total four rows to be filld in a custom way. but they gets overlapped and i can not see any of the table..
They do look, but overlapped, Any hints .. about why its happening
Do i need to make changes into nib?

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)  
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id oneObject in nib)
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
}






cell.iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"beach%d.jpg",indexPath.row+1]];
cell.title.text=[[RArrray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Beach"];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells are resized to the row height. Try setting `tableView.rowHeight = 220`.

**EDIT:** Avoid implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`; if you do, it's called *for every row*, which becomes a problem when your table gets large (see the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) for more)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I follow you, but if it's any help overlapping usually happens because you didn't set the rowHeight for a tableview. Try this -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 220; // Or whatever your cell height is?
}
```